# Showing that every point of X is a limit point of X for a standard order topology.

Tags: general-topology, limits

> Let $[0,1]$ have the standard order topology. Let $Y := \{a,b\}$ have the discrete topology. Consider the product space $X := [0,1] \times Y$. Show that every point of $X$ is a limit point of $X$.

I figured out a way to solve it, but I am not 100% sure whether its correct or not. Can someone tell me if its correct.

[image]

Comment: Did you start by writing down definitions? What do you need to prove to show a point $(s,y)\in X$ is a limit point?

Comment: Any point $x\in [0,1]$ is a limit of other points of $[0,1]$, for example, $x_n=x+1/n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, when $x<1$ and $x_n=x-1/n$, for $x=1$. If you have a point $(x,t)$ in $X$, where $t$ is either $a$ or $b$, then it is the limit of the points $(x_n,t)$ of $X$.

Comment: I know that if X is a space, and A is a subset of X. Then, we can say that a point x \in X is a limit point of A iff for every open set U in X containing x, (U\{x} intersection A) is not equal to an empty set. Limit point of A is A'. Also, standard order topology means that is the subbasis that consists of positive and negative open rays. Here, [0,1] is {(-\infty, 0) | 0 \in X} U {(1, \infty) | 1 \in X}. But how to join [0,1] with Y (having discrete topology) and how to show that its a limit point of X in X ? I got confused there.

Comment: Please format your question using MathJax. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Be more systematic: let $(x,y)$ be in $X \times Y$ and let $O$ be an open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$. By definition of the product topology there are open sets $U \subseteq X$, $V \subseteq Y$ such that $(x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq O$. Now there is some interval $(a,b)$ that contains $x$ and sits inside $U$ (as $U$ is order open; nitpick: we could have $x=0$ and then we'd have $[0,a)$ for some $a$ or $x=1$ and some $(a,1]$ instead; check that this doesn't matter in the following as the argument still goes through), and so we have some $z$ in the interval that is not $x$. That's all we need: $(z,y) \neq (x,y)$ and sits in $U \times V$ hence $O$ and as $O$ was arbitrary, $(x,y)$ is a limit point of the product.